# DPA 4060 and Focusrite Clarett 2Pre: Phantom needed?

Tags: microphone, dpa

Hi guys – Just a quick and probably very basic question: do I need to turn 48V on when I connect a DPA 4060 Mic (MicroDot) through a DPA XLR DAD6001 P48 Connector? I would have think that this is the case however I read on a blog that turning Phantom 48V on would 'fry' the mic. Any thoughts/suggestions please? Many thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Yes it needs phantom power 12v-48v. I've the same mic and adapter so can say this with complete confidence